# Wordpress CSS arranging divs: container/footer to get a 100% landing page

Tags: wordpress, css, height, wrapper, sticky-footer

Im having problem arraning my divs so that I can see a 100% landing page without a vertical scrollbar (I dont want remove that option, i just want a 100% screen page at the start).

I have a header and footer which are outside of my container.

This is my css

```
    html {
        height: 100%;
        font-family: serif;
        font-size: 137.5%;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    }

    body {
        font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        height:100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
   .container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color:#3FC;  

    }

    footer {
        text-align: center;
    width: 100%;    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    }
```

Heres two images to show whats wrong. The container is green, and the footer has 3 colors, all this to see whats actually happening when Im changing things. As you can see the footer is not showing in the first picture but is sticky to the bottom in the second picture. I want to remove this extra-space in the container.

[top of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMjbz.png)
[bottom and footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d96iq.png)

**UPDATE: SOLVED?**
Hi! I just tried something after several hours of searching for examples and trying to applying to my project but it didnt work. Now, please tell me if this is a big no-no in some sort of way but it worked and im happy i was able to do it myself.

What I did was to set heights to my footer and header div. Then in my container div i set `min-height: calc(100% - totalheightvalueofbothdivs);`

And voila, it works. I tried to zoom in and out and still good. Gonna keep troubleshoot in different browsers and such.

Now this is when I have:

```
<header>
<container>
<footer>
```

What Im thinking is that set heights on footer/header might be bad? But I dont need to do that, since I know how big they are anyway and could just use the calc() and dont set them in footer/header.

Answer (score 2):

Please be sure if you want a single page application. In that case your header and footer will be of some fixed height and your container will be covering rest of the space of the scree. Is it what you want? Please see the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    .mainWrap {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }
    .headerMain {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        height: 50px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        background: #fff;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .sectionMain {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        background: #efefef;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 50px 0px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .footerMain {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        border-top: 1px solid #000;
        background: #fff;
        z-index: 1;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="mainWrap">
        <header class="headerMain">Test Header</header>
        <section class="sectionMain">Test Body</section>
        <footer class="footerMain">Test Footer</footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dont fully understand what you mean. My site will have more pages than one - but they all will have same layout and structure. Is that what you mean? Will this work when contents in container gets bigger too - when a real scrollbar is needed, will then footer/header stay on their place?

Comment: If you want to fix Footer and Header, You have to apply CSS "Position:fixed" to both of your elements. Please let me know if you want a code to help you.